# watching netflix on Centos8

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, video, centos, netflix

I installed Centos 8.5.2111 on an Asus. I tried to watch netflix on Firefox 91 but there are codecs and agreements. I set up Widevine and Cisco H264 addons but it doesn't work. Googling indicates that I need ffmpeg and ffmpeg-devel. OK, I run these commands with the following results:

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
[snip]
$ sudo yum localinstall https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:36 ago on Tue 28 Dec 2021 04:58:28 AM PST.
rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm                                                                                    11 kB/s |  11 kB     00:01    
Package rpmfusion-free-release-8-0.1.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
$ sudo yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:51 ago on Tue 28 Dec 2021 04:58:28 AM PST.
Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libSDL2-2.0.so.0()(64bit) needed by ffmpeg-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package ffmpeg-devel-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64 requires libavdevice(x86-64) = 4.2.5-2.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package ffmpeg-devel-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64 requires libavdevice.so.58()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libSDL2-2.0.so.0()(64bit) needed by libavdevice-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
$ sudo yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel --skip-broken --nobest
Last metadata expiration check: 0:12:09 ago on Tue 28 Dec 2021 04:58:28 AM PST.
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libSDL2-2.0.so.0()(64bit) needed by ffmpeg-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package ffmpeg-devel-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64 requires libavdevice(x86-64) = 4.2.5-2.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package ffmpeg-devel-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64 requires libavdevice.so.58()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libSDL2-2.0.so.0()(64bit) needed by libavdevice-4.2.5-2.el8.x86_64
======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                            Architecture                 Version                           Repository                                    Size
======================================================================================================================================================
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 ffmpeg                             x86_64                       4.2.5-2.el8                       rpmfusion-free-updates                       1.4 M
 ffmpeg-devel                       x86_64                       4.2.5-2.el8                       rpmfusion-free-updates                       909 k
 libavdevice                        x86_64                       4.2.5-2.el8                       rpmfusion-free-updates                        97 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================
Skip  3 Packages

Nothing to do.
Complete!
$
```

OK, refreshing my Netflix tab still doesn't work. I need libSDL2. The closest I could find was `SDL` and `SDL-devel` which I installed but it doesn't help install ffmpeg. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with rpm-based distros, but have you tried running
`sudo yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel --nobest`?
Judging by the output, that one could posiibly work.

Also you probably lack some repositories (that's just a guess because you didn't post a `yum repolist`) Here's a [guide I found](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-ffmpeg-in-centos8/), and judging by the output you provided, you didn't fulfill the requirements completely.
My guess is confirmed by [this](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=72010) forum post, in which a CentOS user is having a similar problem with SDL2 libs, and he just had to enable the [powertools repo](http://mirror.leaseweb.com/centos/8/PowerTools/x86_64/os/Packages/) thing.

Comment: I had installed the SDL library manually from here on a hope and a prayer:

https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libSDL2-2.0.so.0%28%29%2864bit%29&submit=Search+...&system=Centos&arch= But this looks like a good resource, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [link](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-ffmpeg-in-centos8/) provided by @savchenko-dmitriy , on the last step before installing `ffmpeg` it said install PowerTools like this `$ sudo dnf config-manager –enable PowerTools`

What's work for me was this :-

```
sudo dnf config-manager --enable   powertools
```

After that I process installing  and it work

```
$ sudo dnf install ffmpeg
$ sudo dnf install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
```